# print rows that have x value in the last column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I´m quite new using numpy, and I have this problem:

Having this array:

```
x = np.array([[ 1,  2,  0],[ 4,  5,  0],[ 7,  8,  1],[10, 11, 1]])

>[[ 1  2  0]
 [ 4  5  0]
 [ 7  8  1]
 [10 11  1]]
```

How could I print the rows with 1 in the last column?
I would like to get something like this:

```
>[[ 7  8  1]
 [10 11  1]]
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advantage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a slice of the array on last column and find which of those equal 1. Based on the resulting boolean array filter your main array:

```
>>> x[:,-1]
array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> x[:,-1]==1
array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> x[x[:,-1]==1]
array([[ 7,  8,  1],
       [10, 11,  1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
y = [ a for a in x if a[-1] == 1 ]
print y
```

Cheers,
Alex